# When generic and ramda library's curry() are used together, generic is not applied

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js, currying

This is a function that finds and returns a value by key in the map, or returns a defaultValue if not found.

```js
import { Map } from "immutable";
import { curry } from "ramda";

export const nullishGet = curry(
  <V>(defaultValue: V, key: string, map: Map<string, V>): V =>
    map.get(key) ?? defaultValue
);
```

And I added a function to set the defaultValue to `[]` when the value I'm looking for is an array.

```js
export const nullishGetArray = nullishGet<unknown[]>([]);
```

the type I expected:

```js
Curry<(key: string, map: Map<string, unknown[]>) => unknown[]>
```

But it was

```js
Curry<(defaultValue: unknown, key: string, map: Map<string, unknown>) => unknown>
```

I also wrote a version that doesn't specify the generic type. like this

```js
export const nullishGetArray = nullishGet([])
//the type of nullishGetArray is Curry<(key: string, map: Map<string, unknown>) => unknown>
```

Simply put, it seems that the generic is not properly applied when trying to use it together with curry.

Is this because Ramda is not friendly with TypeScript, or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Edit objective-zeh-6ye5og]

If I were to write what I actually want without using curry, it would look like the following.

```js
export const nullishGet = <V>(
  key: string | number,
  map: Map<string | number, V>,
  defaultValue: V
): V => {
  return map.get(key) ?? defaultValue
}

export const nullishGetArray = <V>(
  key: string | number,
  map: Map<string | number, V[]>,
  defaultValue: V[] = []
): V[] => nullishGet<V[]>(key, map, defaultValue)
```

###### library version

- ramda: 0.28.0
- @types/ramda: 0.28.23

Comment: Two observations: a) `Curry<…>` and therefore `typeof nullishGet` is a function that's generic over the arguments **list** (or tuple) type. If you want to specify the generic parameter, you'll need to write `nullishGet<[unknown[]]>([]);` or `nullishGet([] as unknown[]);`. (Compare `nullishGet<[unknown[], string]>([], 'x');` or `nullishGet([] as unknown[], 'x');`). b) The type inference of `Curry` does not work at all for generic functions. It seems that it simply replaces the type parameter to `unknown`. This might be a TypeScript limitation, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit awkward, but you can achieve what you're trying to do by moving the around a few things:

```
import Immutable from "immutable";
import * as R from "ramda";

// Define implementation outside of Ramda's curry
function nullishGetBase<V>(
  defaultValue: V,
  key: string,
  map: Immutable.Map<string, V>
): V {
  return map.get(key) ?? defaultValue;
}

// Note the explicit type here
const nullishGetArray = R.curry(nullishGetBase<unknown[]>)([]);

// result type is unknown[]
const result = nullishGetArray("foo", Immutable.Map({ foo: ["bar"] }));
```

I think it's failing with your version because the generic parameter `V` does not have any constraints, and it will default/fallback to `unknown`. In turn, that will override any other type you throw at it.

Comment: So, are you saying that in order to create functions using curry, you need to define their base function without curry first?

Having to write two functions to make one function seems pretty bad....

And errors `(TS2349: This expression is not callable. Type 'unknown[]' has no call signatures.`, 
`TS2554: Expected 3 arguments, but got 0.)` occur in the `nullishGetBase<unknown[]>` part of the fourth line from the bottom in the code you suggested.

Comment: Not sure what your code looks like, but the code snippet above I've verified works as expected. Perhaps there is a typo on your end? Note that the parenthesis for _calling_ the method with its first parameter is outside of the `R.curry(...)` call.

See repo here https://github.com/smonn/typescript-and-ramda